# Avoid 'Do you want to proceed? [y/N]:' in R by auto answering y for all lines

Tags: r

Can this be done in R? where am R script can be run without interruption by any function.

This `Do you want to proceed? [y/N]:` was generated from `renv::restore()`, but regardless, can all promotes be ignored.

Any input is helpful, Thanks.

Comment: One option would be to run a 2nd session of R and use `library(KeyboardSimulator)` to click on the 1st session's console and then continually type "y" and press Enter, or use `Sys.sleep()` to add a delay to it.

Comment: @Baroque That is super hacky and not recommended, there is an option for it, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik all `renv` commands (`restore()` definitely) have the `prompt` argument:

```
prompt  
Boolean; prompt the user before taking any action? For backwards compatibility, confirm is accepted as an alias for prompt.
```

Use `prompt=FALSE` (default is `interactive()`) to turn off the prompting.